# Excel VBA - copy a file from a static folder name and paste into a folder name found in an ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble setting the destination folder name in VBA in Excel to a specific path value from a cell that I have selected. That is, I want to always copy a specific file found a static location into a destination folder that varies based on the cell that I have selected with my cursor.

This is a modification of sub that was previously posted:

```
Sub sbCopyingAFileReadFromSheet()
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String


'source file
sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("C26")
'source folder
SFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("c27")

'destination folder
sDFolder = Sheets("Main").ActiveCell.Value 
''' this is not working here.  I would like the destination folder 
''' to be where I have my cursor but I get 
''' an error : Object doesn't support this property or method '''


'Create Object for File System

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder

If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), (sSFolder & sDFolder), True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Selection` to replace `Sheets("Main").ActiveCell.Value`. Please try the VBA code as below:

```
Sub sbCopyingAFileReadFromSheet()
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String
'source file
sFile = Sheets("Main").Range("C26")
'source folder
SFolder = Sheets("Main").Range("c27")
'destination folder
sDFolder = Selection
'Create Object for File System
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder", vbInformation, "Not Found"
'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), (sSFolder & sDFolder), True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation,"File Already Exists"
End If
End Sub
```

Hopefully it helps you. Looking forward to hearing from you.